# Returns Something To Its Central Place In Soviet History

Tags: word-meaning, usage, countability

A book review for the book "The Soviet Tragedy" by Martin Malia [reads](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0684823136):

> The Soviet Tragedy is an essential coda to the literature of Soviet studies...Insofar as [he] ***returns the power of ideology to its central place in Soviet history***, Malia has made an enormous contribution. He has written the history of a utopian illusion and the tragic consequences it had for the people of the Soviet Union and the world.

I understand (sort of!?) the phrase "*a central place in Soviet history*".  But I don't quite get how the author Malia proactively "*returns the power of ideology to its central place in Soviet history*," since Malia is not a participant of that Soviet history, but a mere author.  If someone, lets say John Doe, did something awesome in the past in America, then the sentence:

> John Doe has a central place in American history.

makes sense to me.

Comment: 1) History = history AND history = historiography. 2) Malia's enormous contribution to historiography lies in putting the power of ideology once more in its proper, central historiographical place where its central role in Soviet history is restored to visibility. 3) There are good authors and bad authors but no mere authors.

Comment: Indeed, history would be only "lore" if there were no history writers.

Comment: @StoneyB  So, a mere average Joe could the put the "*cold war in a central place in American history*"?

Comment: @meatie -- Note that the quote says "**its** central place in history", not "**a** central place in history".  Leninism and Stalinism were permeated by successful attempts to force all politicians and managers to parrot the official party line -- even when the party line changed.  The contrast between the ideology and reality was always a constant theme in people's daily lives.  I cannot imagine how competent historians could somehow forget (or ignore) how central ideology was in the Soviet Union.

Comment: @meatie -- Compared to the role of ideology in the Soviet Union, the Cold War is nowhere near as central to American history.  The great upheavals in American History (1775-1791, 1861-1868, 1933-1938, 1963-1974) were not driven by the Cold War.  Even if "a mere average Joe" were to promote (among historians) a theory that the Cold War held "the central place in American History", he would be wrong.  I would hope that his being wrong would make him unlikely to succeed.

Comment: @Jasper  Would this rewrite be better?  "Insofar as [he] returns the power of ideology to its central place ***in the study of*** Soviet history, Malia has made an enormous contribution."

Comment: @Jasper  I don't quite get how an external observer (historian) could affect, in an after-the-fact manner, a the place of a sub-event/sub-aspect within some larger history.

Comment: @meatie -- This is an even better interpretation:  "Insofar as [he] returns the power of ideology to its central place [as a central theme] in [the study of] Soviet history."  If this interpretation helps you understand it, feel free to annotate your copy of the text.  But to a native-speaker of English, this re-write is unnecessary.  The word "history" is overloaded in ways that cause the original quote to mean the same thing as this longer version.

Comment: @Jasper So, the original is poorly written?

Comment: @meatie No not really. It is written well- and what is appropriate for that mode of writing. If you are still unclear, I can post an actual answer.

Answer (score 3):

**History is a story**

History is a story.  Historians emphasize certain facts, events, and themes.  People who listen to or read history do so either for entertainment, or for general knowledge, or to gather lessons that can help them make decisions in the future.

The original poster is under the impression that the English word "history" primarily refers to "all of the important things that happened in the past".  But according to several dictionaries, this is **not** the primary definition of history.  For example, the [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/history) lists "past events, [especially] when considered as an aggregate" as the fourth definition.

This is because too many events have happened in the past for anyone studying history to know about all of them.  Collins' second and third definitions talk about how we deal with this.  Definition 3 is "the discipline of recording and interpreting past events involving human beings".  Definition 2 is "all that is preserved or remembered of the past, esp in written form".

When the historians have interpreted and condensed history enough that it can be told as a story, we reach Collins' first definition:  "a record or account, often chronological in approach, of past events, developments, *et cetera*".

**How the quote was meant to be interpreted**

The quoted passage was meant to be read by well-educated English speakers.  These readers understand that the primary meaning of "history" has to do with the facts and themes that are emphasized by people who study history.  They understand that the original quote means  "Insofar as [he] returns the power of ideology to its central place [as a central theme] in [the study of] Soviet history".

Because this meaning will be understood by the intended audience, the quote is well-written.  But if you think of "history (everything that happened)" and "the study of history (the facts and themes that historians think are important)" as two different things, then feel free to annotate the quote to show that it is talking about the second meaning.

**Differences of opinion**

A common English saying is that "History is written by the winners".  The biases of historians profoundly affect what we read in our history books.  Historians also suffer from fads.  Usually key information is either secret, or has been lost or overlooked.

By the way, if you have done any study of history at all, you have your own interpretations of history.  For purposes of this discussion, you are also a historian.  You might be more or less knowledgeable than some professional historians about various topics.  You might be more or less able to convince someone about the truth or or importance of something that happened in the past.  But if you think something is right or important, you are certainly entitled to an opinion.  Your opinion might be more or less correct than that of a professional historian.

**Irony**

Ideology did have a central role in the Soviet Union.  The Bolshevik party was founded to develop and promote a particular ideology.  After it seized control of the remnants of the Russian Empire during World War I, it structured the government, military, agriculture, and industry so that its ideology would be considered in every significant decision. For example:

- There was a parallel hierarchy of "political officers" in the military.
- The chief ideologist was always one of the highest ranking members of the Politburo.
- Leninism and Stalinism were permeated by successful attempts to force all politicians and managers to parrot the official party line -- even when the party line changed.
- The contrast between the ideology and reality was always a constant theme in people's daily lives.

When the contrast between ideology and reality was too stark, Soviet historians were expected to side with ideology.  For that matter, when the contrast between current ideology and past ideology was too stark, Soviet historians were expected to side with current ideology.  This made histories written by Soviet historians unreliable.

Comment: So, I misunderstood the phrase "*Soviet history*"?

Comment: @meatie -- You were using definition #4 of "history", not definition #1.

Comment: Definition 1 appears to require the countable form, like "***a/the*** *Soviet history*", while definition 4 appears to require the uncountable form. The original example uses "*history*" in the uncountable form ("*its central place* ***in Soviet history***"). So, I thought I should use definition 4.

Comment: Definition #1 has both a countable form and an uncountable form.  The uncountable form is more common, because most educated native-speakers of English have a subject called "History" or "Social Studies" in most years of their primary and secondary education.  The countable form is used in book titles and book reviews, such as "A History of the Soviet Union".

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I am not a native speaker, but this is to me explainable.

Whoever she is, the author or the reader,

> > ..Insofar as [he] returns the power of ideology to its central place in Soviet history, Malia has made an enormous contribution.

She is saying **he** ( whom I do not know so I assume someone else, not Malia ). And here the word **place** wouldn't mean a certain spatial point, but rather a synonym with **role** or **performance**.

Since she writes

> > **He** has written the history of a utopian illusion and the tragic consequences it had for the people of the Soviet Union and the world.

From which is implied is **the HE** is stressing **the role of the ideology of ( the socialism )** in the history of Soviet Union that caused the tragic consequence and the utopian illusion excited by it.

In shorter terms, she is simply saying **the HE** is telling the story of the **power of the socialism** that caused many tragic consequences in Soviet.